# Adding schema markup attributes into Quill.js inner HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, quill, parchment

I’m trying to add a custom button to add FAQ markup schema within my quill editor (Question, AcceptedAnswer). So far I have it working with Registering the buttons in the toolbar, and then slightly alternating them upon save with Nokogiri to add the markup on save, but when the quill container loads upon edit it wipes out these custom attributes. Has anyone else had success creating custom markup buttons before?